# Is there a way to list files uploaded on the server trought JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

I've been searching for a long time with no succeed about this: I want to upload files to a server with a form but after that I want to show in a JSP the list of files stored in the server so is that posible? how can i achive that? of course what I want is to read the list of files compared and show them in the jsp with more data.

Comment: You'll need to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you two guys has helped me a lot, I've finally come out with the solution or at least an option to make it easier for me, and as I'm uploading a file, what I can do is to capture the whole path with the file name then insert it on the table and whenever I try to get an array with the list of items it will directly show the link to the file, I think if I do this way I won't get a mess when listing data with their corresponding files uploaded on the server.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how are you going to store the files. If you going to do it in the file system then you can just list everything in the folder you're saving the files to. If you going to store the files in the database - then just list all of the file names in the files table.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, all JSPs are statically generated before the client-side script is run, so any Java in the page is run before the user has a chance to upload the files. If you want to do it on the same page, all you need to do is an AJAX call to a script that can grab the data or another page with the data and append it to the DOM.

If all you want to know is if it is possible to get a list of files from the server, then yes, JSPs use normal Java, which can see anything it has permissions to see in the filesystem.

A good place to start would be here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html